# What does "problem is bigger than any one city" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> But mayors and councilors can only do so much about **a problem that is far bigger than any one city or town**.

Does it mean the problem is the biggest problem and no city and town can deal with it? And mayors and councilors have done their best?

Answer (score 0):

This indicates thsat the problem, whatever it is, affects many cities, perhaps an entire country or the whole world. Since it doesn't say what the problem is in this quote, there is no way to say more. It doesn't say this is the "biggest" problem -- there are many problems larger than any one city. It doesn't say that "mayors and councilors have done their best", or that they haven't. It does say that there is a limit to what such people can do, and implies that even their best will not solve the3 problem, whatever it is.  This might follow a statement that "mayors and councilors" have not taken important steps, or that they have done all that is possible, or something in between. It probably follows some sort of statement about what the "mayors and councilors" have or have not done. Again, without context, one cannot say more.